# Where is append() implementation?

Tags: go, built-in

I cannot find implementation code of append() or any other builtin functions  anywhere? I tried finding the code through godoc and using jump-to-definition feature of IDE's. May be i am looking at wrong places. Could anyone show me the way to see actual implementation?

Comment: If you want to see the builtin API see http://golang.org/src/builtin/builtin.go

Comment: @sridhar i did. There is no implementation there.

Comment: Yes it's the API. The source will probably be written in a combination of C/C++/assembly which may also be open source but you'll have to look a little harder.

Comment: The source is pretty much all in Go, though part of it is in a hardcore-reading form as that part resides in the code generation package. Details in my answer below.

Comment: You can check out the Append() example in the following link http://blog.golang.org/slices

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may be interested by :

- the code generating bit `append` is in here https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.16.7/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/ssa.go
- and `growslice`, used by the former, and that lives in here : https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.16.7/src/runtime/slice.go